# p == NULL takes less time than !p in c++

Tags: c++, performance

I am doing **Leetcode**https://oj.leetcode.com/ recently. Suppose p is a pointer, an interesting thing is that the running time is different when I use

```
if(p==NULL)
```

and

```
if(!p)
```

the first one take less time than the second one. 
Is there any difference between them ?
Thanks!

---

Update:
[image: root == NULL, 14ms]
[image: !root, 15ms]
[image: root == nullptr, 12ms]

Comment: On a side note you should use nullptr instead of NULL.

Comment: They are exactly the same. If you measure any difference in "running time" then probably your benchmark is broken or you are misreading its results.  If you are really sure that it seems to be running differently then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes the benchmarking so that others can try to reproduce it

Comment: The have the same semantic meaning. Not sure why the former would be faster than the latter.

Comment: Thx laurent. I tried nullptr. It is faster : )

Answer (score 6):

I would expect all implementations to produce the exact same compiled code for both versions.

`NULL` has a value of zero. And `!p` is testing if p is zero. So in both cases, p is being compared to zero.

I seriously doubt you've found any performance difference between the two. And, if you are, I suspect some other element is at play there.

Comment: I just update the question. Plz check the pics. Thx.

Comment: @billlipeng: I don't get this. Your two versions do something different in the else block? Shouldn't you be testing the same block of code with *only* the difference that we are discussing? Why would you introduce another element? What platform is this? What does the machine code look like? Did you try it in release (non-debug) mode?

Comment: 1.two versions do something diff in the else block? I am running the exactly same code. Please check carefully.  2.Shouldn't u be testing the same block of code with only the difference that we are discussing? Please read carefully. 3.Why would u introduce another elem?Please specify the meaning of the other elements.  4. What platform is this? This is a online judgement platform. https://oj.leetcode.com/ "5.What does the mach code look like? Sorry, I have no idea. In my original question I said I am doing Leetcode now. 6. Did you try it in release mode? The platform does not support this.

Comment: @billlipeng: Ok, I see it now. Under the covers, the *exact same* test is needed in both cases. In all C++ compilers I've used, it would be optimized to the exact same machine code instructions. I stand by my statement that *I would expect all implementations to produce the exact same compiled code for both versions* but perhaps some implementations are just different. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Leetcode.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I think I'd better take compiler class to understand these.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the optimizer on. C++ performance in debug builds isn't meaningful.